# POST API (not form post) to create a JSFiddle

Tags: php, api, jsfiddle

I'm working on some demos where we need to generate some code dynamically for each user. We would like to POST a JSFiddle API end point to create a new fiddle programatically from our back end. However, reading the documentation, it seems that the only POST function supported is designed for forms, not APIs, and loads a page with the jsFiddle loaded.

Is there some way I can post to a jsFiddle API and get back a URL to the jsFiddle I can direct users to?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already found this:

[Display a Fiddle from POST](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/post.html)